# http server error 500 when running.php on AWS PHP Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing a web application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with PHP configuration. When I submit an HTML form my PHP file that handles the information going to my MySQL db is getting a Server error 500. I don't know how to resolve this as my PHP knowledge is limited.

```
<?php
  $hostname='SOMENAME.rds.amazonaws.com';
  $username='masteruser';
  $password='**********';

  try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=riderdb",$username,$password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO riderInfo(partyNM, numParty, numCooler, phoneNum,pickUp)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["partyName"]."','".$_POST["numParty"]."','".$_POST["numCooler"]."','".$_POST["phoneNum"]". ','".$_POST["pickUP"].''")";
  if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
  }
  else{
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
  }

  $dbh = null;
  }
    catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Comment: ElasticBeanstalk does a pretty good at creating logs and making them available to you.  What do they say?  And is this a test or school project?  PHP has had prepared statements for quite some time.  The code you're showing is pretty dangerous as is.  But let's get it working first.

Comment: What do you mean by dangerous?

Comment: It is susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) attacks as you're building up the query string from URL parameters.  But, again, that (probably) doesn't matter if the code doesn't run.

Comment: The logs showed me an issue with the Values line of the code. Syntax error.

Comment: @stdunbar I've corrected the issue to get the page to load etc. However, I'm still getting a syntax error around the insert statement. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you show the error?  Edit your post and include it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the syntax of my insert statement. I had to many quotations in it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO riderInfo(partyNM, numParty, numCooler, phoneNum, pickUp)
VALUES ('".$_POST["partyName"]."','".$_POST["numParty"]."','".$_POST["numCooler"]."','".$_POST["phoneNum"]."','".$_POST["pickUP"]."')";
```